# How should I arrange the mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, row

Let's-
I have  1,000,000 of users signed in. It will be a facebook (Not really facebook) type of site.

**So I have huge amount of data to be stored in my database.** Please help me choosing the database design.

**Design 1:**

```
Database count    : 1,000,000 [i.e. user_1, user_2, user_3] 
Table count       : 15 Per Database
Row Count         : 100+ Per Table
```

**Design 2:**

```
Database count    : 15
Table count       : 1,000,000 Per Database
Row count         : 100+ Per Table
```

**Design 3:**

```
Database count    : 1
Table count       : 15 Per Database
Row count         : 10,000,000++ Per Table
```

What should I choose?

Design 1 : Which have Huge amount of Databases in the server.
Design 2 : Which has Huge amount of tables in a database.
Design 3 : Which has Huge amount of Rows in a table.

Comment: If you opt for #1 or #2, do you have the slightest idea of how you'd manage migrations for 1 million objects?

Comment: If you want to take profit of a RELATIONAL DBMS, which mysql is, the 3 is the only serious solution. Otherwhise you should use hadoop or something else.

Comment: Loosely related: [MySQL can take more than an hour to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348578/mysql-can-take-more-than-an-hour-to-start)

Comment: Why 15 databases in Design #3?

Comment: Sorry that should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 may actually be a practical impossibility in reality, as each database requires its own resources and you will likely exhaust whatever system you use to implement it. And there's the operational nightmare of having to set up a new database every time a new user joins. This choice is consistent with the dictionary definition of "insane".

Option 2 is only slightly behind option 1 on the insanity scale, except it may be possible to implement.

Option 3 is no big deal and is a situation that occurs routinely. Use this option.

For a traditional relational database, up to about 20M rows is considered "small" for a table (no citation, just experience). 20M-200M is "medium", above that "large".

For non-traditional RDBMS, eg redshift, and NoSql DBs (mongo, cassandra, hadoop, etc) 10M rows is "tiny" and billions of rows is no big deal.