# MySQL can take more than an hour to start

Tags: mysql, percona

I have a mysql (Percona) 5.7 instance with over 1Million tables.
When I start the database, it can take more than an hour to start.
Errorlog doesn't show anything, but when I trace mysqld_safe, I found out that MySQL is getting a stat on every file in the DB.

Any idea why this may happen?
Also, please no suggestion to fix my schema, this is a blackbox.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of tables.  On a side note, this question might be more fitting in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1 million tables? Get a new blackbox.

Comment: great database design - 1Million Table * 3 Handles for 1 InnoDB Table = 3Million File Handles.

Comment: Wow. This is talking donkey territory. It's not amazing it works badly, it's amazing it works at all.

Comment: Did you try to add more resources to the machine ? RAM, Disk space ? you need redesign your DB. why do you have so many tables ?

Comment: @4EACH It's a sharded db, One db per customer. Kind of like wordpress....100 Tables per db, some 20k customers sitting on 50 servers... I'm trying to consolidate in one reporting slave server, so, I can build a pipeline and consolidate my data. The multi-slave works fine, but starting the db takes ~2 hours now. Thanks for asking so nicely!

Comment: @Younes Is it part of a replication cluster?

Comment: @Eilyre It's a reporting server, that is replicating from all shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be 2 issues (other than millions of tables)!

1. When MySQL start, and a crash recovery is needed, as of 5.7.17, it needs to traverse your datadir to build it's dictionary. This will be lifted in future releases(8.0), as MySQL will have it's own catalog, and will not rely on datadir content anymore. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-recovery-tablespace-discovery.html) states that this isn't done anymore. It's true and false. It doesn't read the 1st page of ibd files, but It does a file stat. [Filed Bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79025)
2. Once it finished (1), it starts a new process, "Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine.". That of course open all the files again. Use disable-partition-engine-check if you think you don't need it. [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_disable-partition-engine-check)

All this can be observed using sysdig. very powerful handy dtrace like tool.

> sysdig proc.name=mysqld | grep "open fd="

Ok, now, it's time to reduce the number of files.